# loop over list and ouput two unique numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very new to Python.
I have 20 numbers in a list, i want 2 unique values each time. So ideally i end up with 10 rows and each row has two unique numbers that have not been used before. I have something like this but it's displaying a number more than once.

```
numberList=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
myset = set(numberList)
rows = len(numberList)//2
i = 0
while i < rows:
    random_nums = random.sample(myset,2)

    print(random_nums)
    i += 1

OUTPUT: 
['13', '8']
['19', '8']
['11', '9']
['16', '7']
['1', '10']
['11', '20']
['16', '18']
['18', '2']
['20', '10']
['7', '4']
```

Comment: So 10 pairs of unique values (set of a 2) not occurred before from, in a list?

Comment: remove them from the list once sampled

Comment: important distinction to make @depperm is that it should be removed from a copy of the list since we do not want to iterate over a list that is changing

Comment: or just create list that stores the nums and later check if they are in that list

Comment: np.random.shuffle(x); for r in np.reshape(x, (10,2)): print(r)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

- You do not need `numberList` later
- The number of pairs you need divides the length of the list with no reminder

You can use this pretty straightforward and efficient approach. Sampling 2 random elements from the list and removing them as long as the list is not empty.

```
import random

numberList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18",
              "19", "20"]

while numberList:
    a, b = random.sample(numberList, 2)
    numberList.remove(a)
    numberList.remove(b)
    print(a, b)
```

An example output:

```
9 14
13 12
7 5
10 2
15 20
19 4
11 1
18 3
17 6
8 16
```

If you do need to use `numberList` later in your code, the next efficient approach will be to handle a set of picked elements. You will need a bit more complicated logic:

```
import random

numberList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18",
              "19", "20"]

taken = set()

pairs = len(numberList) // 2

for _ in range(pairs):
    a, b = None, None
    while a is None or a in taken:
        a = random.choice(numberList)
    taken.add(a)
    while b is None or b in taken:
        b = random.choice(numberList)
    taken.add(b)
    print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove Items from the "numberList" or better said "myset".

```
import random

numberList=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
myset = set(numberList)
rows = len(numberList)//2
i = 0
while i < rows:
    random_nums = random.sample(myset,2)

    myset.remove(random_nums[0])
    myset.remove(random_nums[1])

    print(random_nums)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have one more object:

```
seen = set()
```

And on the body of the while loop:

```
while i < rows:
    random_nums = set(random.sample(myset,2))
    if not random_nums.issubset(seen):
        print(random_nums)
        seen.update(random_nums)
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you right then you don't want repeat the numbers. Like if a number has appeared before, it shouldn't appear again. Then you can probably delete the elements of `myset` accordingly. Like this:

```
import random
numberList=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
myset = set(numberList)
rows = len(numberList)//2
i = 0
while i < rows:

    random_nums = random.sample(myset,2)
    myset.remove(random_nums[0])
    myset.remove(random_nums[1])
    print(random_nums)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
from random import choice

numberList = 
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17",
"18","19","20"]

for i in range(10):
    a = choice(numberList)
    numberList.pop(numberList.index(a))
    b = choice(numberList)
    numberList.pop(numberList.index(b))
    print([a, b])
```

Answer (score 0):

As the lists get large, sampling and removing is more work than you need to do and will be inefficient.  Instead, use [np.random.shuffle](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html)

```
numberList= ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
np.random.shuffle(numberList)
for r in np.reshape(numberList, (10,2)):
   print(r)
```

Output:

```
['18' '20']
['17' '16']
['11' '1']
['5' '13']
['7' '14']
['19' '15']
['6' '8']
['9' '12']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `random.shuffle` to do that job, following way:

```
import random
numberList=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
random.shuffle(numberList)
rows = len(numberList)//2
for i in range(rows):
    random_nums = numberList[2*i:2*i+2]
    print(random_nums)
```

Note that `random.shuffle` alters list in place, i.e. if you would add `print(numberList)` at end of my code it will print 20 numbers, but in random order.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, if you know you will always work with integers, I think it would be easier to convert them all to integers, as I did in the following example with a list comprehension. Since you are specifying exactly 20 numbers and 10 pairs, I hardcoded those numbers in the script, but you can easily set variables instead.

```
import random


numberList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
              "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]

# If you know you always have numbers, convert them all to integers → easier
numberList = [int(x) for x in numberList]

myset = set()  # Will be used to add any number NOT seen before
numberList_pairs = []  # Will be used to build a list of unique pairs

while len(numberList_pairs) < 10:  # You need 10 pairs in that new list
    pair = []

    # While you don't have a unique pair, keep generating random numbers
    while len(pair) < 2:
        random_num = random.randint(1, 20)  # 1 to 20. Both ends are included

        # If the number hasn't been seen before
        if random_num not in myset:
            myset.add(random_num)
            pair.append(random_num)
    numberList_pairs.extend([pair])  # Add the pair as a list

for pair in numberList_pairs:
    print(pair)
```

Here would be a sample output:

```
[20, 14]
[16, 2]
[13, 10]
[6, 12]
[9, 18]
[3, 19]
[17, 11]
[1, 5]
[8, 4]
[15, 7]
```

Note: If you do happen to need the output to be lists of strings, you can convert back to strings in the final loop like so:

```
for a, b in numberList_pairs:
    a, b = str(a), str(b)
    print([a, b])
```

And you would get the same output as you originally posted:

```
['11', '9']
['2', '15']
['7', '12']
['13', '3']
['19', '20']
['1', '14']
['16', '5']
['18', '8']
['10', '6']
['4', '17']
```